# Parsing XML using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

Given the XML below, I need to parse it and output names of all books and the authorname if any of the authors are from the USA.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<bookstore>
  <categories>
    <category>Cooking</category>
    <category>Children</category>
    <category>Fiction</category>
  </categories>
  <books>
    <book>
      <title>Everyday Italian</title>
      <authors>
        <author>
          <name>Giada De Laurentiis</name>
          <country>USA</country>
        </author>
      </authors>
      <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
    <book>
      <title>XQuery Kick Start</title>
      <authors>
        <author>
          <name>James McGovern</name>
          <country>Sweden</country>
        </author>
        <author>
          <name>Per Bothner</name>
          <country>USA</country>
        </author>
      </authors>
      <price>49.99</price>
    </book>
  </books>
</bookstore>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"Your giant xml string here");
var books =
    doc
        .Descendants("book")
        .Select(bookElement => 
        new
        {
            Title = bookElement.Descendants("title").Single().Value, 
            Authors = bookElement.Descendants("author")
                .Where(authorElement => authorElement.Descendants("country").Single().Value == "USA")
                .Select(authorElement => authorElement.Descendants("name").Single().Value)
        });

foreach(var book in books)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Book: " + book.Title);
    Console.WriteLine("Authors: " + string.Join(",", book.Authors));
}
```